# jquery not working on internet explorer after deploy on iis 7

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, internet-explorer, bootstrap-4, iis-7

i have deployed my website in iis7, but when i access from client-side using Internet Explorer, bootstrap and jquery doesn't work correctly, but it worked very well when i access from server as localhost, and an error hundel from jquery in script console, here i put some image show the difference between both sides
[image: inside Server side]
[image: in client-side]

and here the error are handled from jquery
[image: console error]

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 5 , Jquery 3.3.7 and bootstrap 4.2
please help and I'm up form more information
Regards

**Edit:**
 I'm sorry for the language ;

First Error : Expected identifier

Seconde Error : Unable to get "fn" property from reference null or undefined

and :

Internet explorer version 11.523

Comment: Could you do us a favor and translate the second error to english. I would prefer not have to copy it by eye and type it into a translator.

Comment: I suggest you could also check the IE browser version, from the screenshot, it seems that you are using different version, please check the related plugin and make sure it support IE browser.

Comment: OK ! just seconde I'll edit

Answer (score 0):

issue Resolved : I have just added in my html head x-ua-compatible META tag;

```
<meta http-equiv="x-ua-compatible" content="IE=11">
```

Then everythings works fine;

The origin of this problem is compatibility with Internet Explorer 11;

***Reference :***

https://devhammer.net/2014/05/27/asp-net-mvc-bootstrap-and-internet-explorer-compatibility-view/